# Compression in the space of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm looking for formal representations, mostly drawing from algebraic graph theory (open to any other framework this could be possible, of course) that are conducive to compression of graphs (networks), something that is not just converting a graph G=(V,E) to it's computer file representation and then compressing the file, but a compression model with a formal generative mathematical description for the compression as well as re-prodution of the original graph from the compressed form. I am not seeing much discussion on graph compression, any thoughts or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about this, but have you looked into the `sparse6` encoding associated with `nauty`?  It's detailed in the [Nauty user guide](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/nug.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Rebecca. I took a brief look, it's interesting, although I am not sure if it's possible to get to what I was looking for with this representation. What I was looking for is more of a mathematical discussion of space of graphs, and how structure in this space can be exploited to describe a natural compression model within that space. The nauty package sounds like could be useful for doing some simulation and experimental validations, but I am hoping to find some theory on the subject first.